# MySQL Query - Get Customers who have not bought all parts of a single product ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay so I have 2 tables. One table for `Product List` and one table for `Orders`. There will be several of the same `ProductID` in my Table1 since each `ProductID` has several parts to it (IE: Part 1 of 7.)

The `PartNumber` will be a number. How do I design my query to find me all the customers who have purchased one of the part numbers, but not all the part numbers for a single product ID?

I'm just learning the basics of MySQL so any help would be much appreciated!

Table1 - Product List

```
UniqueIDKey
Product ID
PartNumber
```

Table2 - Orders

```
UniqueIDKey
Product ID Ordered
PartNumber Ordered
Customer ID
```

So an order might look like this:

```
UniqueIDKey: 77
Product ID Ordered: 1001
PartNumber Ordered: 3
Customer ID: 2000001
```

And, several rows of my `Table1 - Product List` might look like this:

```
UniqueIDKey     Product ID     PartNumber
77              1001           1
78              1001           2
79              1001           3
```

Comment: What's your strategy? I mean what you have tried so far? Please feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to know the total number of parts under each product prior
  to knowing which customers bought some parts of a product but not the
  whole.
- The query enclosed by table alias `B` provides count of parts for
  each product.
- The query enclosed by table alias `A` provides for each
  `<customer,product>` pair the total number of bought parts.
- Now the rest is to match whether the total number of bought parts is
  less than the total number of parts of a product.

In this approach the query would look like below:

---

```
SELECT 
 A.customer_id,
 A.product_id,
 A.total_parts_of_product_customer_purchased AS total_purchased,
 B.total_parts,
 B.total_parts - A.total_parts_of_product_customer_purchased AS didnot_purchase
FROM (
  SELECT 
    customer_id,
    product_id,
    count(part_number) AS total_parts_of_product_customer_purchased 
  FROM Orders AS ordr 
  GROUP BY 
      customer_id, product_id
) AS A 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
    product_id,
    count(part_number) AS total_parts
   FROM product_list AS pl 
   GROUP BY product_id
) AS B 
ON A.product_id = B.product_id
WHERE A.total_parts_of_product_customer_purchased < B.total_parts
ORDER BY A.customer_id;
```

Comment: Currently, the amount of Parts for each ProductID varies rather randomly. The ProductID's generally have between 1 and 35 parts. Any suggestions with this?

Comment: What's the problem with variable number of product parts? Are you facing any issue? Different products might have different number of parts. That seems legit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to get all combinations of customers,product_id's and part_numbers. `left join` orders table on to this result to get customers who haven't ordered all the parts in a product.

```
select c.customer_id,p.product_id
from (select product_id,part_number from product_list) p 
cross join (select distinct customer_id from orders) c
left join orders o on p.product_id=o.product_id and p.part_number=o.part_number and c.customer_id=o.customer_id
group by c.customer_id,p.product_id
having count(o.part_number) < count(p.part_number)
```

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but this query is running extremely slowly for me. Any tips to speed it up?